# To consume WCF service with PIC microcontroller

Tags: wcf, pic

I had established WCF Duplex service and client pair.

In this case I have used both windows running machines as a client and service. and I have used wsDualhttpbinding as a protocol.

I want to use PIC32 board(with wifi) as client. So which protocol I should use to consume WCF service in PIC?

What kind of request should be generated from PIC to communicate with WCF service??

Comment: I don't think a PIC is powerful enought to implement the XML parsing that SOAP requires. Go for a more simple protocol (see http://www.microchip.com/forums/m201133.aspx for a similar question).

Comment: will you please suggest me a protocol that is compatible with both wcf service and PIC32??

Comment: Depends on the data that you want to send. A proprietary binary format with fixed size packages over a plain TCP connection is often easiest.

Comment: @SPandya `inline code` should not be used to highlight random terms, but to show code.

Comment: They were the keywords of the question.

Comment: @AndersAbel I know that its a simplest one to use Plain TCP. but right now I have loaded webpage on PIC and transferring data via GET/POST request through PC. but I want to reduce a burden from PIC by getting webpage on server(not on PIC). so I moved to WCF but as u say Xml parsing is not possible in  PIC as it has low ROM. Is there any way to make webpage staying on server and PIC accessing it through Plain TCP??

Comment: The WCF service can be created as a REST services and simply return a binary stream to the caller. You can put anything in the returned data  part of the reply you want.